# Delay hide() from toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that when clicked is either visible or hidden using jQuery's toggle() method.

Using toggle() is it possible to delay it from being hidden for a few seconds, while not delaying the visibility?

```
$('.myelement').click(function() {
    $('.myelement').toggle();
});
```

Comment: $('#myelement').delay(1000).toggle();

Comment: Wouldn't that delay the element being hidden and shown?

Comment: Are you essentially asking "Can I prevent the user from toggling the element for 1 second after a state change on the element?"

Comment: sorry my bad, the right answer should be of @hsz

Comment: @Palpatim Not exactly. I don't want the toggle to be prevented when invoke, only delayed.

Comment: Once you click it and it dissapears, how do you click it to make it visible again? It's gone !

Comment: Now you've edited the question, and the posted answer is suddenly wrong.

Comment: You're right, I've reverted it. That answer got me close enough to being able to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$('.myelement').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
    $(this).delay(1000).hide();
  } else {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

Or simplier:

```
$('.myelement').click(function() {
  $(this).delay($(this).is(':visible') ? 1000 : 0).toggle();
});
```